# Switching between forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Anytime I want to display a new form, I create a new form object and hide the current form. 
For example:

```
this.Hide();
new Form2().Show();
```

In this way, a new object keeps getting created over and over, and the old form is still running but hidden somewhere.

I would like to know what would be the most appropriate way to do so, I've been doing this for long time and anytime I do this I feel like I am doing it wrong. I mean how can we access the previous object and set it back to show instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Write a global/static FormManager class to track this. with create-on-demand logic for the forms.

Comment: You can use [Object pool pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) to manage all your created forms, and have a method to retirieve a form that checks if a form instance is available, and if not it creates one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Application.OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) property to get already opened form object and show that.

> The OpenForms property represents a read-only collection of forms
>   owned by the application. This collection can be searched by index
>   position or by the Name of the Form.

```
Form1 frm1 = Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1 ;
if (frm1 != null)
{
    frm1.Show(); 
}
```

Comment: That worked pretty well Habib and I think solved my problem, I'll accept your answer.